# How to make button stands on top of the listbox

Tags: c#, scroll, listbox, controls

I have custom listBox :

```
  public class List:ListBox
{
    private Button but;

    public List()
    {

        but = new Button();
        but.Location = this.Location;
        but.Width = this.Width;
        but.Height = 100;
        this.Controls.Add(this.but);



    }
```

I want something like this:

[image]

I want button to be on top of the listBox, and if it have scroll , to maintain on top. 
What i get is this 

[image]

Is it possible to do that? Because listBox isnt container component and i heard that isnt very smart to play with it, but i dont have other way.

Comment: Why do you need it inside the list box? Can't you just put it above?

Comment: You can use `ListBox.SendToBack()` to have the button overlap the list box

Comment: @emsimpson92 i put this.SendToBack() line , but it doenst work

Comment: @DavidG , yes , i could do that but how?

Comment: Well you put a button on the form, then underneath it you put the list box. Not sure why that is confusing :)

Comment: I have option that i can drag listbox, and button should follow the listBox @DavidG

Comment: So make a user control that has those items in it and drag the wrapper control instead. It's quite strange to be dragging controls around though.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your ListBox name is **TestLB**. Then you can use the codes below.

```
Button but;
but = new Button
{
    Location = TestLB.Location,
    Width = TestLB.Width,
    Height = 100,
    Text = "Click"
};
this.Controls.Add(but);
TestLB.SendToBack();
```